# Check if IPropertySymbol has a backing field

Tags: c#, roslyn

I started playing with roslyn few days ago and i am trying to write an extension method which tells if an `IPropertySymbol` has a backing field, so i thought a property has a backing field if and only if the following does not apply(as far as i am concerned):

- IF its Abstract
- IF its Extern
- IF its ReadOnlyProperty
- IF the Getter or the Setter has no Body or Empty body

so i came up with

```
public static bool HasBackingField(this IPropertySymbol property)
        {
            return !(property.IsAbstract || property.IsExtern || property.IsReadOnly);
        }
```

My questions are

- Did i miss any condition?
- How do i check for the last condition? i found `GetMethod` and `SetMethod`properties in `IPropertySymbol` but i don't know to check if they have a body

example to start up with

```
                var code = 
                @"class XYZ
                   {
                      public int x => 4;                                  //HasBacking field : false IsReadOnly

                      public int m { get { return 0;}}                    //HasBacking field : false IsReadOnly     

                      public int y { get; set; }                          //HasBacking field : false Null body for setter or getter

                      public int z { get { return 0; } set { } }          //HasBacking field : false Empty body for setter or getter

                      private int _g;
                      public int g                                        //HasBacking field : true Getter and Setter has no empty Bodies
                       {
                           get { return _g; }
                           set { _g = value; }
                       }
                  }";

            var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("xxx").AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree);
            var classSymbol = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("XYZ");
            var propSymbols = classSymbol.GetMembers().OfType<IPropertySymbol>();
            var results = propSymbols.Select(ps => ps.HasBackingField()); //should be [false false false false true]
```

Comment: Even if the getter and setter have a body, there might not be a backing field... e.g. `public int X { get { return 0; } set { } }`

Comment: @ThomasLevesque true except i am the one writing my code and i won't write such useless property ;), any other cases in mind?

Comment: Without trying it out: I think you can just check if `GetMethod` and `SetMethod` are of type `BlockSyntax`. If they are, they have a body (empty or not). Another approach I can think of is just checking if it's null and/or if it has descendent nodes. You'll have to check how it functions exactly.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel `GetMethod` and `SetMethod` can never be of type `BlockSyntax` and are not null when the body is null or empty, does this mean that i have to use the `PropertyDeclarationSyntax`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to look at the syntax representation rather than the actual symbol -- the syntax is at a lower level than the symbol and contains the raw information we're interested in: looking at individual statements.

This seems to do what you're interested in:

```
internal static bool HasBackingField(this PropertyDeclarationSyntax property)
{
    var getter = property.AccessorList?.Accessors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsKind(SyntaxKind.GetAccessorDeclaration));
    var setter = property.AccessorList?.Accessors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsKind(SyntaxKind.SetAccessorDeclaration));

    if (setter?.Body == null || getter?.Body == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    bool setterHasBodyStatements = setter.Body.Statements.Any();
    bool getterHasBodyStatements = getter.Body.Statements.Any();

    return setterHasBodyStatements && getterHasBodyStatements;
}
```

Note that I'm not convinced this is reliable enough to conclude that there is a backing field available, but it follows the idea you had by checking if there is a body or not.

I haven't added the other checks you had in mind but these can trivially be added (either use the symbol as you already do or look through the `PropertyDeclarationSyntax` its modifiers/attributes).

### ---

Full code to test it out yourself:

```
public static void Execute()
{
    var code =
@"class XYZ
{
  public int x => 4;                                  //HasBacking field : false IsReadOnly

  public int m { get { return 0;}}                    //HasBacking field : false IsReadOnly     

  public int y { get; set; }                          //HasBacking field : false Null body for setter or getter

  public int z { get { return 0; } set { } }          //HasBacking field : false Empty body for setter or getter

  private int _g;
  public int g                                        //HasBacking field : true Getter and Setter has no empty Bodies
   {
       get { return _g; }
       set { _g = value; }
   }
}";

    var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
    var root = tree.GetRoot();

    foreach (var prop in root.DescendantNodes().OfType<PropertyDeclarationSyntax>())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prop.HasBackingField());
    }
}
    }

internal static class Extensions
{
    internal static bool HasBackingField(this PropertyDeclarationSyntax property)
    {
        var getter = property.AccessorList?.Accessors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsKind(SyntaxKind.GetAccessorDeclaration));
        var setter = property.AccessorList?.Accessors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsKind(SyntaxKind.SetAccessorDeclaration));

        if (setter?.Body == null || getter?.Body == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        bool setterHasBodyStatements = setter.Body.Statements.Any();
        bool getterHasBodyStatements = getter.Body.Statements.Any();

        return setterHasBodyStatements && getterHasBodyStatements;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know i can do it with `PropertyDeclarationSyntax` but was hoping for some way with `IPropertySymbol` because that code is much cleaner.

Comment: Think about it this way -- what would it mean for HasBackingField to report anything from a metadata reference? Roslyn doesn't dive into method bodies, so that's why `IPropertySymbol` can't give this to you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't cover the following case of lazy initializing a field using a property:  `private Mutex guard; private Mutex Guard { get { return guard ?? (guard = new Mutex(false, "name")); }}`